# Input and button both have a height of 30px but the button is smaller

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm programming in React.js and I want to make a search bar but the text input tag is bigger than the button tag even though they are both 30px, and it looks pretty ugly so I want to fix it

Here is my code:
HTML / JSX

```
    <div className="searchBarContainer">
      {showSearch && (
        <input
          type="text"

          className="searchBarInput"
        />
      )}

      {searchText && (
        <button
          type="button"
          className="cancelSearchBtn"
        >
          <i className="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
        </button>
      )}

      {!showSearch ? (
        <button className="activeIcon" type="button" onClick={handleSearchBar}>
          <FaSearch />
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button className="searchBtn" type="button" onClick={handleSearch}>
          <FaSearch />
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
```

css / sass

```
    .searchBarContainer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;

      height: 30px;
      width: 100%;

      .searchBarInput {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;

        height: 30px;

        width: 80%;
        max-width: 600px;

        border-top-left-radius: 50px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;

        &.searchBarInput:focus {
          outline: none;
        }
      }

      .searchBtn {
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        border: 0px solid transparent;

        height: 30px;

        min-width: 40px;
        max-width: 40px;

        border-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 50px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
      }
```

I've had this problem many times before but I could never figure out why

Comment: I don’t understand how you can easily use react and sass, but you can’t figure out such a basic question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your .searchBarInput should help, it adjusts how the height is calculated with borders.

You can read more in the MDN Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Another quick note, i'd recommend changing your button width from a 40px min/max width to something like `width: fit-content` which you can checkout [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content) if you're interested in reading more about it.